# How to extend a Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

for example, I have an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  value1: number;
  value2: number;
}
```

I'd like to add a sum() method that would give me a sum of values on any instance of this interface. What is a Typescript's way of doing this?

I need to be able to write a function like this:

```
function printFooSum(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(???);
}
```

and the function should not involve manual assignment of foo properties to some other class.

Comment: I need to work with classes I don't control. There are multiple of them, and the only thing in common is that all implement the common interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is the following:

```
interface Foo {
  value1: number;
  value2: number;
}

class Foo {
  public static sum(foo: Foo) {
    return foo.value1 + foo.value2;
  }
}

function printFooSum(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(Foo.sum(foo));
}
```

But maybe there is a more elegant way...

Comment: P.S. In practice, resorted to creating a wrapper for the interface instance and calling the function on the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Extend a TypeScript interface via the `extends` keyword:

```
interface Foo {
  value1: number;
  value2: number;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  sum() : number;
}
```

Implement the interface the following way:

```
class Baz implements Bar {
  public value1: number;
  public value2: number;
  sum() : number { return this.value1 + this.value2; }
}
var bar : Bar = new Baz();
```

Note: the `implements Bar` part is optional. Instances of `Baz` would still be assignable to `Bar` slots, as they have the required properties. However adding `implements Bar` will enforce the compiler to check the `Baz` class implements the `Bar` interface, throwing a compile time error on `Baz` if it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do something like:

```
interface Foo1 extends Foo {
  suma(): number
}

interface Foo{
  value1: number;
  value2: number;
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces

---

You add this:

> I need to be able to write a function like this:

```
function printFooSum(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(???);
}
```

---

But this part does not understand well:

> and the function should not involve manual assignment of foo
>   properties to some other class.

you do not want to do this?

```
function printFooSum(foo: Foo) {
  console.log(foo.value1 + foo.value2);
}
```

Comment: @SergeyAldoukhov sorry but this part does not understand well -> and the function should not involve manual assignment of foo properties to some other class. Perhaps because of my bad English, but this will help you